# What is the difference between 'I see the walking robot.' and 'I see the robot walking.'?

Tags: meaning

I want to know the difference between the two sentences.
1. I see the walking robot.
2. I see the robot walking.
I want to know the difference in meaning between the two sentences.
Please, tell me the difference.

Answer (score 2):

As a noun phrase, a *walking robot* is a robot that has been designed to walk. As a verb phrase, a *robot walking*, is a robot that happens to be walking.

So, we can have the following phrases:

> The **walking robot** on the shop floor is currently **standing still**.
>   Look at that **robot walking** around the shop floor—it must be one of those new **walking robot** models.

Or, to follow the phrasing in the question:

> I see the **walking robot** ***walking***.
>   I see the **walking robot** ***standing still***.

Comment: Did I not say the same thing? This is unfair . I got no upvotes 

Answer (score 0):

Walking Robot(noun)= A robot that walks

Robot walking is an action.

You see a robot when it's walking

Comment: So what's the difference between the OP's two sentences?

Comment: In walking robot, walking is the main attribute of the robot. That's the only thing it does. Whereas, seeing a robot walking doesn't necessarily mean that it can't do anything else besides walking.